# Chrome saying multiple-backgrounds css is invalid

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to set an multiple css backgrounds and I'm testing in Chrome and it says this style is an invalid property value.

It has the yellow exclamation mark icon and the strike-through in dev tools:

[image]

Here is the style:

```
.illyBody{
    background:transparent url(night_body.png) bottom left repeat-x, #27235b url(night_stars.png) 16px left repeat-x !important;
    background:transparent url(night_body.svg) bottom left repeat-x, rgb(39, 35, 91) url(night_stars.svg) 16px left repeat-x !important;
}
```

What is invalid about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 issues.  The [spec for background](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background) is as follows:

```
[ <bg-layer> , ]* <final-bg-layer>

<bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> 
<final-bg-layer> = <bg-image> || <position> [ / <bg-size> ]? || <repeat-style> || <attachment> || <box> || <box> || <'background-color'>
```

Notice that only `<final-bg-layer>` contains `<'background-color'>`.  So your first background in your property cannot have a color as yours does (transparent).

Then in the section about `background position` you will see the following:

> Note that a pair of keywords can be reordered while a combination of keyword and length or percentage cannot. So ‘center left’ is valid while ‘50% left’ is not.

You have `16px left` which is backwards and as this note mentions is invalid.  So with those two issue in mind, you css would be as follows:

```
.illyBody{
    background: url(night_body.png) bottom left repeat-x, #27235b url(night_stars.png) left 16px repeat-x !important;
    background: url(night_body.svg) bottom left repeat-x, rgb(39, 35, 91) url(night_stars.svg) left 16px repeat-x !important;
}
```